# Netbeans support for struts 2?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ide, struts2

I have just started learning struts 2. I have purchased the book named Struts 2 in action. But I want to use an IDE for developing Struts 2 applications. I basically use netbeans.

Please tell me how can i develop applications using netbeans. Also, it would be great if somebody can point out a few tutorials on the same.

regards

P.S. I haven't used eclipse. Is it advisable to switch to it for struts 2, (if it is better than netbeans in this case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using NetBeans IDE then it is a good idea to find a plugin for Struts2 in NetBeans IDE as it will provide you tools for Struts2 maintaining the comfort you are already having with NetBeans IDE.

1. For NetBeans IDE 6.9 and above the
   plugin for Struts2 is available in
   the NetBeans Plugin Portal.  Please
   visit the link
   http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=23467
   and download the plugin.  This plugin will get downloaded as a ZIP file.  After unzipping it you will find three NBM files.
2. Using the Tools Menu > Plugin option open the Plugins dialog box and using the Downloaded plugin.    Select those NBM files and install all of them.
3. Now when you start a new Java Web > Web Application project, you will get option to choose web framework with Struts2 as one option, choose Struts2

with regards
Tushar Joshi, Nagpur

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Netbeans, but this IDE seems to [handle natively only Struts 1.x](http://netbeans.org/features/web/web-app.html), but you can use [plugins](http://beans.seartipy.com/2008/08/04/struts-2-plugin-for-netbeans-ide-nbstruts2support/) for the Struts 2.x framework.

Regarding the tutorials, [Google can help you to find some of them](http://www.google.com/search?hl=fr&source=hp&q=netbeans+struts2&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=), like this [one](http://beans.seartipy.com/2008/07/30/hello-world-web-application-using-struts-2-in-netbeans-ide-61/). [The NetBeans wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Struts2OnNetbeans) seems also helpful..